# Express as function of $z: \sin(a^2+b^2)+\cos(a^2+b^2)i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Where $z = a + bi$

and

$$f(a+bi) = \sin(a^2+b^2)+\cos(a^2+b^2)i$$

How could I write this in terms of $z$?

$$f(z) = ???$$

> FYI, this describes a spiral of some sort. I stumbled across it making some mathematical artwork. Extra thanks to anyone who knows what kind of spiral.

Comment: It may help to note that $a^2+b^2=|z|^2$

Comment: $a^2+ b^2 = |z|^2 = z\bar z$

Comment: Wait, how is it a spiral? The function is $\sin(\text{something}) + i\cos(\text{samething})$, which is clearly a circle.

Comment: Are you taking the curves in the input plane, where the output (or its Real or Imaginary Part) is constant? Like $\sin(x^2+y^2) = \frac12$ ?

Comment: That doesn't work either; it results in concentric circles.

Comment: Take a look at it: http://yokefellows.net/andrew/spiral.png
Note that the rendering technique uses the distance traveled from each point on the image to determine the value.  The lighter, the less you moved.  The darker, the further you moved.

Comment: @AndrewSpringman -- Interesting... So you're plotting $|f(z)-z| = \sqrt{(\sin(x^2+y^2)-x)^2+(\cos(x^2+y^2)-y)^2}$. I would call that technically not a spiral (a 1D subset of 2D), but a surface (a 2D subset of 3D), if brightness is a 3rd dimension. Can we define a curve from this, a ridge where the brightness is maximized? It looks like it's brightest at only one point near the centre.

Comment: @AndrewSpringman -- I think we can get a constant-height ridge (a spiral) from the difference in absolute values: $h = |z|-|f(z)-z|$.... Yes! I find that the max is $h = 1$, and the min is $h = -1$, both of which occur when $x\cos(x^2+y^2) - y\sin(x^2+y^2) = 0$; or, in polar coordinates, $r^2 = \frac\pi 2 - \theta$. This is Fermat's Spiral. (The part where $h = 1$ starts at $(x,y) = (\sin(1),\cos(1))$; and $h = -1$ starts at $(0,0)$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $|z|^2= a^2+b^2$ $$f(z) = \sin(|z|^2)+\cos(|z|^2) i  = i e^{-i|z|^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$f(z) = \sin(|z|^2)+\cos(|z|^2) i$$